# Prevent the user from trying to access a specific url

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have a controller where it controls all the what to do when the specified url is entered e.g. login, register etc. What I want to do is if the user is on the `/register` page and when he tries to access `/login` via typing directly on the url, the page won't load/redirect to `/login`, hence preventing the user from accessing `/login`. I have tried `redirect('/to_the_url');` so far but what I wanted was not to redirect. I hope anyone gets my query. Thanks guys.

Comment: why do you think like this ? if a user on register page and the same user is trying to open the login page in another browser tab or window then what will happen ?

Comment: Even when a user finished registration and the user still on the register page and he wants to open the login page in different window or tab then what will happen ?

Comment: @www.sblog.in: I just want to restrict the users from /login(the controller). Also if they want to login, a login link which shows a dialog with the login form is supplied, that's why I think it is unnecessary to let them go to `/login` since it has already been provided.

Comment: then you can't restrict using php or server side code rather you have to use javascript or jquery to check and redirect user to the register page if it is already opened

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, you have a login controller that you use to show login form as a dialog but you dont want direct access to the login controller in the address bar of the browser, is that it?